# How can I make my list of lists better indexable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to store data in a list of lists, such that each sample, which has a variety of info associated with it, all together in a list, and then store a large number of those in a list. What I have so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from operator import itemgetter # For sorting

class XaDatum (object):

    fields = {'name':0, 'ki':1, 'amt':2, 'rep': 3, 'stage':4, 'variety':5, 
              'date':6, 'comments':7}

    def __init__(self, name, ki, amt, rep=None, stage=None, variety=None, 
                 date=None, comments = None):
        for item in (name, rep, stage, variety, date, comments):
            if item is not None:
                item = str(item)
        ki = int(ki)
        amt = float(amt)
        self.datum = [name, ki, amt, rep, stage, variety, date, comments]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.datum[self.fields[key]]

    def copy(self):
        return XaDatum(self['name'], self['ki'], 
                          self['amt'], self['rep'], 
                          self['stage'], self['variety'], 
                          self['date'], self['comments'])

    def __setitem__(self, key, item): 
        if key in ['name', 'rep', 'stage', 'variety', 'date', 'comments']:
            item = str(item)
        if key == 'ki':
            item = int(item)
        if key == 'amt':
            item = float(item)
        self.datum[self.fields[key]] = item

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.datum)

    def show(self):
        print("{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}  {4}  {5}  {6}  {7}".format(
                self['name'], self['ki'], self['amt'], self['rep'],
                self['stage'], self['variety'], self['date'], 
                self["comments"]))


class XaData (object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.count = 0

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.data)

    def append(self, name, ki, amt, rep=None, stage=None, variety=None, 
               date=None, comments=None):
        self.data.append(
            XaDatum(name, ki, amt, rep, stage, variety, date, comments))
        self.count += 1

    def show(self):
        for i in self.data:
            i.show()

    def copy(self):
        returnme = XaData()
        for item in self:
            returnme.data.append(item.copy())
        return returnme

    # Result points to the same memory! Changes to the returned
    # znoselonglist will result in changes to the original!
    def filter(self, inverse=False, min=-float('Inf'), max=float('Inf'), 
               ki_min=-float('Inf'), ki_max=float('Inf'), rep=None, stage=None,
               variety=None, date=None, comment=None):
        returnme = XaData()
        for item in self.data:
            match = ((item['amt'] >= min)
                     and (item['amt'] <= max)
                     and (item['ki'] >= ki_min)
                     and (item['ki'] <= ki_max)
                     and (rep is None or item['rep'] in rep)
                     and (stage is None or item['stage'] in stage)
                     and (variety is None or item['variety'] in variety)
                     and (date is None or item['date'] in date)
                     and (comment is None or item['comment'] in comment))
            if match ^ inverse:
                returnme.data.append(item)
        return returnme

    def sort(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 0:
            args = ('name', 'ki')
        self.data = sorted(self.data, key=itemgetter(*args))

    def unique(self, key):
        key_list = [item[key] for item in self.data]
        return sorted(list(set(key_list)))

    def unique_kis(self):
        kilist = [item['ki'] for item in self.data]
        return sorted(list(set(kilist)))

    def unique_names(self):
        namelist = [item['name'] for item in self.data]
        return sorted(list(set(namelist)))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    da = XaData()
    da.append('x00', 35, 501, stage='B', variety='V1')
    da.append('x01', 40, 309, stage='D', variety='V2')
    da.append('x02', 37, 450, stage='D', variety='V1')
    da.append('x03', 35, 470, stage='A', variety='V2')
    da.append('x04', 40, 378, stage='B', variety='V1')
    da.append('x05', 45, 770, stage='A', variety='V2')
```

If I run this I can do:

```
In [1]: da.show()
x00  35  501.0  None  B  V1  None  None
x01  40  309.0  None  D  V2  None  None
x02  37  450.0  None  D  V1  None  None
x03  35  470.0  None  A  V2  None  None
x04  40  378.0  None  B  V1  None  None
x05  45  770.0  None  A  V2  None  None

In [2]: daf = da.filter(variety='V1')

In [3]: daf.show()
x00  35  501.0  None  B  V1  None  None
x02  37  450.0  None  D  V1  None  None
x04  40  378.0  None  B  V1  None  None

In [4]: daf[0]['amt'] *= 0.2

In [5]: daf.show()
x00  35  100.2  None  B  V1  None  None
x02  37  450.0  None  D  V1  None  None
x04  40  378.0  None  B  V1  None  None
```

But I can't do,

```
In [6]: daf[:]['amt'] *= 0.2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/nathan/work/simo_znose/<ipython console> in <module>()

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

So my question is, how would I make slicing work? Or, alternatively, is there already a datatype or something that already does what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Nathan

Comment: What exactly do you expect `daf[:]['amt']` to return? Or what result do you expect to happen? Do you want to multiply every `amt` value with `0.2`?

Comment: The `item = str(item)` line in `XaDatum.__init__()` does not what you think it does. Read http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements.

Comment: @Poke: Yeah, I would want every `amt` value to be multiplied by 0.2...or, well, it'd be nice...

Comment: More specifically, it would do, `for item in daf[:]: item['amt'] *= 0.2`

Comment: @pillmuncher: Thanks for pointing that out! Is there a standard way of doing what I was trying to do there? It feels wrong to do, `for item in ('name', 'rep', 'stage', 'variety', 'date', 'comments'): exec(item+'='+'str('+item+')')`

Comment: @user733664: it does feel wrong, doesn't it? Trying to programmatically reassign variable names is often ugly. But since your end-result is a plain list, why are you bothering? Use a list comprehension: `optional_data = [item if item is None else str(item) for item in ('rep', 'stage', 'etc...')]; self.datum = [str(name), int(ki), float(amt)]; self.datum.extend(optional_data)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate tables like these quite conveniently with NumPy's [record arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-multiple-fields-at-once).  NumPy is a de facto standard for array operations in Python.

You could also think of using a database table, for instance through [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Yeah, I figured numpy might be the answer. This was a bit of an exercise to see how far I could go with just python. Putting class XaDatum within class XaData was the only way I could think of to allow indexing by a key such as 'variety' as opposed to remembering the column number.

Comment: @user733664: I think that your pure-Python approach is fine (I would implement `copy()` with `return XaDatum(*self.datum)`, though; I would also store all the values directly with the right type instead of string, so as to avoid conversions :).  I would guess that in essence, NumPy does something similar.  What I like with NumPy is the ability to use the lighter `my_arr.variety`, in addition to `my_arr['variety']`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like slicing is working as expected. `daf[:]` returns a copy of `daf.data` which is a list -- so you get an error when you try to index the result with `'amt'`, because you can't index a list with a string.

To reiterate poke's comment, it's unclear what you want `daf[:]['amt']` to do. It looks as though you want to alter the `'amt'` of *all* XaDatum objects contained by a copy of `daf`. But is that actually what you want? If so, you'll have to alter `XaData.__setitem__` (and `XaData.__getitem__` for the sake of completeness) to accept string indices.

You'll also need to alter `XaData.__getitem__` so that slicing returns a new `XaData` object instead of a new `list` object. You should probably do that anyway -- in any case, that is expected slicing behavior.

You'll probably find it helpful to know about [slice objects](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) if you're going to write custom `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods.

Comment: I should add that you're doing something very complex here. Are you sure you can't do what you want with simpler classes, or perhaps even just a few built-in types?

Comment: Any pointers as to how `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` would need to be altered?

Comment: Looking back over this, I'm afraid that question is just too broad and complex for me to answer right now. A couple of notes though: you can also create `__getslice__` and `__setslice__` methods, which should simplify slicing -- but not string indexing. And if you want to do things like `*=` slice assignment, you'll _also_ have to override `__mul__` and `__add__` and...  frankly I think you're barking up the wrong tree with this.